# Usar Claims en asp core 3 para seguridad personalizada

Tags: asp.net-core

Hola a todo el mundo soy un novato con asp core 3 y estoy desarrollando un sistema de cero, el sistema tiene una seguridad personalizada por temas que no entrare a detallarlo, lo que sucede que deseo usar Claims pero estoy estancado y no encuentro nada en la red sobre como usar las claims, tengo esto:
Para ponerlos en contexto esto es el esquema de base de datos de seguridad personalizada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para asignar los usuarios quiero usar Claims y esto es lo que tengo primero en el startup.cs en sección de configure services

```
       #region Implementacion de Claims

       services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddCookie();
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(opt =>
       {
            opt.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       });
       #endregion
```

y en la sección configure siempre en el startup.cs tengo esto:

```
       app.UseAuthentication();
       app.UseAuthorization();
       app.UseCookiePolicy();

       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
       });
```

en el controller tengo esto:

```
[HttpPost]
          [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
          public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UsuarioModel Entidad)
          {
               var eData = await _iUser.ObtenerPorEmail(Entidad.email);

               //Si no encuentra el correo no esta registrado el user
               if (eData == null)
               {
                    TempData["Titulo"] = "Error";
                    TempData["Mensaje"] = "El usuario con que intenta conectar no existe, pongase en contacto con el admnistrador del sistema";
                    return RedirectToAction("Mensaje", "Home");
               }
               //Si llega hasta aquí y es primera vez permite generar el password
               if (eData.firsttime)
               {
                    return RedirectToAction("SavePassword", eData);
               }
               else
               {
                    //Si no es primera vez verifica si es correcto el pass y se conecta
                    if (eData.ComparePass(Entidad.passmain, eData.salt, eData.password))
                    {
                         //Aqui codigo de claims
                         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }

                    TempData["Titulo"] = "Error";
                    TempData["Mensaje"] = "El password esta equivocado";
                    return RedirectToAction("Mensaje", "Home");
               }

          }
```

Bueno ya llego al punto donde debo de implementar los claims pero no se como:
1) ¿Crear las claims con los datos en ese momento?
2) ¿como la reutilizo la claim para validar si se conecto?
3) ¿Como puedo obtener los claims para reusarlo y deshabilitar en el menu opciones?
4) ¿Como las destruyo al cerrar sesion?

Se que son muchas preguntas :(, pero si alguien tiene algun lugar donde pueda ver un ejemplo claro y pueda leer mas de esto lo agradecere o si pueden poner algun ejemplo sería genial, de antemano gracias a la comunidad.

Comment: Aunque interesante, la pregunta en si es demasiado amplia. Leiste algo de toda la documentacion sobre claims? hiciste algun intento? en general creas las claims cuando logueas al usuario y estas van y vuelven con cada pedido..

Comment: Tienes mucha razón ya he logrado resolver el problema, con prueba y error gracias

Comment: Entonces podes contestar tu propia pregunta ;)

Comment: Si que si ya compartí por si alguien tiene la misma duda :) saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(update) funciona perfectamente en 3.1 o superior lo he probado con 5.x tambien
Ok. me voy a autoresponder porque he dado con la solución leyendo y a prueba y error quiero compartirla con la comunidad por si alguien necesita información
Esto funciona en ASP CORE 3.X y claro se que pueden haber mejores formas así que siempre si sabes de una mejor les invito a postearla para aprender más

Primero configurar startup.cs sección ConfigureServices

```
       #region Implementacion de Claims

       services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddCookie();
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(opt =>
       {
            opt.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       });
       #endregion
```

Es importante decir que esta es una configuración de minima seguridad  es por eso que uso  la opción opt.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
pero pueden leer mas y hacer mas seguro sus claims

Muy bien. continuemos siempre en startup.cs sección Configure

```
       app.UseAuthentication();
       app.UseAuthorization();
       app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

Agregar estas opcione sino estan.

Eso es para que nos funcionen las claims

vamos a responder las preguntas

1. ¿Como Crear las claims con los datos?
   Bueno suponiendo que ya nos logueamos y tenemos los datos necesarios, para crear las claims, recordemos que estos son cokies que se pueden mantener en el equipo del cliente

Lo primero necesito estos usign en el controller

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
```

Luego ya podemos crear los claims

```
                 var ClaimList = new List<Claim>();
                 ClaimList.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, eData.nombre + " " + eData.apellido));
                 ClaimList.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, eRol.rolname));
                 ClaimList.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, eData.email));
                 ClaimList.Add(new Claim("userid", eData.userID.ToString()));
```

como pueden ver muy sencillo una lista de claims y luego agregar hay "ClaimTypes" estos vienen predefinidos por si usas identity puedes usarlo sin identity como he hecho yo pero tambien puedes definir los tuyos "userid", "Nombre", "mierda" lo que quieras :D
"eData" es una clase mia que trae los datos del logueo.

Luego de crear los Claims necesarios  debemos de crear la identidad usando la lista de claims creada arriba, esto para que podamos usarlos luego esto se hace muy facil

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(ClaimList, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

bueno solo falta hacer el logueo de por si le he puesto que si no me desconecto estas claims solo duren 8 horas

```
                 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                                               CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                               new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                                               new AuthenticationProperties
                                               {
                                                    IsPersistent = true,
                                                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8)
                                               });
```

2. ¿como la reutilizo la claim para validar si se conecto?
   Es decir como se que esta conectado y existen las claims, muy facil solo buscamos una claim que yo cree ejemplo "ClaimTypes.Name" ahi guarde el nombre del user

   ```
       ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
       var data = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
   ```

si data es nulo if (data != null) entonces no existe las claims si no es nulo pues el user esta conectado.

3. ¿Como puedo obtener los claims para reusarlo y deshabilitar en el menu opciones?
   bueno como pudiste ver en la respuesta a la pregunta dos es sencillo por que busque las claims para ver si existian.  Pero esto es en el controller, es la forma de hacerlo pero digamos que lo necesitamos en la vista para deshabilitar html o en el _layout.html

lo primero es usar los siguentes using

```
@using System.Threading;
@using System.Security.Claims;
```

luego ya podemos hacer los siguente

```
</head>
<body>
    @{


        int conectado;
        string nombreuser = "";
        string nombrerol = "";
        //seguridad modulos
        string pro = "";
        string prd = "";
        string fac = "";
        string inv = "";
        string pre = "";
        string ped = "";
        string rep = "";
        string seg = "";


        var userconn = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

        if (userconn != null)
        {
            conectado = 1;
            nombreuser = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            nombrerol = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
            pro = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Proveedores").Value;
            prd = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Producción").Value;
            fac = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Facturación").Value;
            inv = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Inventarios").Value;
            pre = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Presupuestos").Value;
            ped = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Pedidos").Value;
            rep = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Reportes").Value;
            seg = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("Seguridad").Value;

        }
        else
            conectado = 0;
```

y estas variables la podemos usar como querramos en las vistas o paginas razor

y la pregunta final.

4. ¿Como las destruyo al cerrar sesion?
   Esto en el controller

   await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

de esa forma las destruyo aunque no haya terminado el tiempo que defini de existencia de las claims.

bueno y ya esta espero le sirva a alguien
saludos

Comment: recuerda aceptarla en 24 horas!!!!